# Invoke worklight SQL adapter procedure using AJAX

Tags: ajax, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Can someone give an example of how to invoke and receive a response from an SQL adapter in worklight using AJAX call? I'm using worklight 6.0

I have security at the app level. I need to invoke a procedure that doesn't need authentication (example: Registering an account) and hence need to invoke the adapter using AJAX

This is my adapter:

```
var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'UserInfo',
                    procedure : 'addUserInfo',
                    parameters : [ customerData.firstName,
                            customerData.lastName, customerData.email,
                            customerData.province, customerData.zipPostal,
                            customerData.phoneNumber, customerData.streetName,
                            customerData.streetNumber, customerData.country,
                            customerData.city ]
                };
                WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                    onSuccess : insertUserSuccess,
                    onFailure : insertUserFailure
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you just want to invoke an Adapter procedure using Ajax from some client.

Is it the same as this other question ?

[Calling Worklight adapter from external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118162/calling-worklight-adapter-from-external-app)

You can check the details of the HTTP API here

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_http_interface_of_the_prod_server.html?lang=en

Update:
Also note that if you have any security tests configured, different than "wl_unprotected" (your adapter is 100% public with that, be careful!!) you may need  extra steps to handle authentication.

If you have a default adapter, without any security test set, you may receive a 401 unauthorized in your first request, and in the body of the 401 you may find a WL-Instance-ID property, that you must send together with a new request to get authorized to use it.

Update 2:
Worklight/MobileFirst Platform doesn't enable CORS (so you can't "naturally" call adapters using ajax from an external web page). It may be possible to workaround that by using a gateway (IHS maybe) that adds the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to all adapter responses. Note that you are handling a security thing, so make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Hi David,

Using the following request example:
"http://localhost:10080/TestProject/console/api/Adapters/get/UserInfo"

I get a 404 not found. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try using the "Invoke Procedure" option from Worklight Studio ? The URL to use will the same used by the invoke procedure without the "/dev/" in the middle of it

Comment: Thanks I used the invoke procedure and saw the invocation on the browser. This is the format:
http://<worklightserver>:<portnumber>/<context-name>/invoke?adapter=<adapterName>&procedure=<procedureName>&parameters=[]

Different from the one in the link though. But this format worked.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight (6.3 and below) adapters can work only with the Worklight Server.
If you plan on using Worklight adapters, you are required to use the API as provided by the Worklight framework - the code mentioned in the question.

You can still use regular AJAX requests - but those won't/cannot be requests sent to/by the Worklight adapter.

```
WLJQ.ajax( "some-URL" )
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

If the destination does require going through the Worklight Server, and it is not protected by any realm, what is the problem then? Send the request.

Perhaps you should not protect the app at the environment level but rather at the procedure level (set the security test on the adapter procedure in the adapter XML and not on the environment in application-descriptor.xml).

Perhaps you need to better explain your specific scenario...

Comment: If I remove protection at the app level then how do I allow the first page to be a login page? 

Some click/action needs to be done before the challenge is presented.

I have used AdapterAuthentication to take care of the login and keeping security at the app level. But it will not allow me to invoke any other adapters since WL.Client.connect was done in the wlCommonInit(), all requests now need to be authenticated. 

I just want to be able to invoke this particular procedure to sign up without authentication.

Comment: Try adding securitytest="wl_unprotected" to that specific procedure.

Comment: I added the following as suggested but it doesn't treat them differently.

<procedure name="addUserInfo" securityTest="wl_unprotected"> </procedure>
 <procedure name="addUserNamePassword" securityTest="wl_unprotected"></procedure>
 <procedure name="getMaxUserID" securityTest="wl_unprotected"></procedure>