# MobileFirst - Remove -secure- sentence from the adapter response

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

It's possible to remove the "/*-secure-" sentence from the response of the worklight adapter?

```
/*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":true,"result":"CC: No subscription found for user :: 11111"}*/
```

version: Mobilefirst 7.0.0

Comment: Yes, it is. But it will be impossible to show you all millions of methods to do that in every thinkable situation. At least add info/tags on: Programming language? Also, showing what you've tried makes sense. This seems so trivial!

Comment: i want to remove it before responding, in the same adapter, not in the back-end

Comment: that doesn't really explain why you're having a problem with simplest string manipulations

Comment: the back-end waits a Json without the "/*-secure-" sentence, I need the adapter does not send that sentence, I have no control over the backend.

Comment: I understand that, but still, you're not giving nearly enough information. In what kind of data do you have the reply? Are you restricted by anything to not use normal string operation to replace the unwanted string by an empty string?

Comment: its is a feature of MobileFirst Adapter, only if you know these software you can help me

Comment: MobileFirst adapters are developed by using XML, JavaScript, and XSL. so your question is really just a JavaScript string handling question.

Comment: This response is generated automatically by the adapter without any JavaScript code. to fix it you must configure something else in the adapter, perhaps with security realms or something similar

Comment: I don't think so; the adapter is specified to return valid JSON, so it's a bug. You either get that fixed, or you work around with something that first parses the response. I was assuming you're doing the latter.

Comment: it's not a bug, it is the normal behaviour of the adapter, is a security measure of worklight, I want to disable it

Comment: Then this is not a programming question, but an admistration question. Also: *NEVER* disable security features because you can't figure out how to work with them; there needs to be a way, and you as a developer need to find it.

Comment: i know that you will always get JSON wrapped in /*secure */. This is to prevent using WL server for XSS attacks

Comment: Can you update the question with version of MobileFirst Platform that you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the answers in this other OS question

[Calling Worklight adapter from external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118162/calling-worklight-adapter-from-external-app)

I believe it is not possible to remove the /*-secure from the response. As responded in that question, it is a feature to avoid XSS atacks.