# invoking worklight adapter from external application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am trying to invoke worklight adapter from external application. I also got the answer in [Calling Worklight adapter from external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118162/calling-worklight-adapter-from-external-app) thread. However I dont want to send adapter name, procedure name and parameters as query params. Rather, I want to send them as payload inside request body. Pls suggest answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using MFP v7.0+ you know that each MFP adapter is exposed as a REST API as well.
you just need to remove the security so external applications can access that REST API easily. 
Not sure if its healthy to reduce security.
but you can mark the (via the adapter xml file) method as "wl_unprotected"